# UWP WebView2 ERR_NETWORK_ACESS_DENIED when loading an IP address (your internet access is blocked)

Tags: uwp, ip-address, webview2

After installing the WebView2 components for UWP and creating a project using [these instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/get-started/winui2), the web view cannot load a local IP `Source="http://10.20.30.59/"`.

[image: ERR_ACCESS_DENIED]

- The same URL works in WPF WebView, however I need to migrate because of other issues.
- The same URL works in other browsers, just not in WebView2. "Normal" URLs like https://bing.com work fine in the WebView2.
- Turning the firewall off still doesn't allow the content to load.
- Turning off the Windows antivirus under Virus & threat protection settings does not help.
- The `CoreWebView2NavigationCompletedEventArgs.IsSuccess` value is `false` and `WebErrorStatus` is `ConnectionAborted`.
- Under DevTools > Network > Headers, the failed page has the value Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin. A visit to https://developer.chrome.com/blog/referrer-policy-new-chrome-default/ shows that this can be modified with Chrome flags, but I don't know how to run those flags to verify this is not the problem.
- The feedback area has some similar issues like https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Feedback/issues/2145, but not one that shows how to debug it.
- In the Package.appxmanifest, adding *Internet (Client & Server)*, *Internet (Client)*, *Private Networks (Client & Server)*, and *Remote System* capabilities does not help.
- Using Node JS + Node Package Manager to run a local server works on `Source="http://10.20.30.106:8080/"`. This leads me to believe the problem is with the source itself. https://devpractical.com/host-a-html-page-on-localhost/#nodejs-section
- The UWP sample WebView2Samples-master\SampleApps\webview2_sample_uwp from https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Samples works fine using the problematic address. Why?

Below is the minimal reproducible example from the instructions:

```
<Page
x:Class="WebView2_Test.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:WebView2_Test"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
xmlns:control="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls"
Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

<Grid>
    <control:WebView2 x:Name="wv2"
                      Source="http://10.20.30.59/"/>
</Grid>
```

This involves first installing [Edge Canary as recommended](https://www.microsoftedgeinsider.com/download); installing the .NET desktop, C++ desktop, and UWP development tools in Visual Studio; and installing the **Microsoft.Web.WebView2** and **Microsoft.UI.Xaml** *prerelease* NuGet packages.

How to debug what is preventing the source from loading?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT thanks for the suggestion, but it doesn't make a difference. Besides, the sample provided by MSFT doesn't have any Content URI declarations and still works, so that is not the solution

Comment: However, I did find the missing capability, which is Private Networks (Client & Server). As noted by the question, I had tested that before, so go figure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By comparing to the Microsoft sample, I found the missing capability, called **Private Networks (Client & Server)** in Package.appxmanifest. This is the only requirement for my project.

For whatever reason, when getting back to the project, this capability had gotten unchecked, so maybe restart Visual Studio or otherwise ensure that this capability has really been registered.

Comment: Thank you - turning Private Networks on worked for me too